# unexpected EOF and syntax error:

Tags: bash, scripts

I can run below codes line by line using terminal without problem but when I run the script file I got

```
line 14: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
line 30: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

the script file is:

```
# this script produces edited rinex files from uncompressed rinex files
echo "NECESSARY FILES ARE UNCOMPRESED OBSERVATION (.o) FILES

# example: rnxEditGde.py -d amc20130.18d.Z -rate 30 -out amc2.gz

shopt -s nullglob
shopt -s failglob

i=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*[0-9][0-9]o' -printf 'x' | wc -c)
grep "MARKER NAME" *.[0-9][0-9]o > grep_file
awk -F'[: ]' '{print $1}' grep_file > station_ids

function pl {                
  sed -n "$1p" $2
}

for (( j=1; j <= i; j++ ))
do
ids=$(pl $j station_ids)

rnxEditGde.py -d $ids -rate 30 -out $ids.gz

done
```

Comment: Look at line 2: no ending `"` in `echo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use https://www.shellcheck.net/ , it will help you find the issues with the script:

```
$ shellcheck myscript

Line 2:
echo "NECESSARY FILES ARE UNCOMPRESED OBSERVATION (.o) FILES
^-- SC1009: The mentioned syntax error was in this simple command.
     ^-- SC1078: Did you forget to close this double quoted string?

Line 10:
grep "MARKER NAME" *.[0-9][0-9]o > grep_file
     ^-- SC1079: This is actually an end quote, but due to next char it looks suspect.
                 ^-- SC1078: Did you forget to close this double quoted string?

Line 14:
  sed -n "$1p" $2
         ^-- SC1079: This is actually an end quote, but due to next char it looks suspect.
             ^-- SC1073: Couldn't parse this double quoted string. Fix to allow more checks.

Line 24:

^-- SC1072: Expected end of double quoted string. Fix any mentioned problems and try again.
```

So you should quote the argument to `echo` in line 2

Answer (score 0):

> echo "NECESSARY FILES ARE UNCOMPRESED OBSERVATION (.o) FILES

This line should end up with "(every opening double quotes require closing double quote)

> echo "NECESSARY FILES ARE UNCOMPRESED OBSERVATION (.o) FILES"